# Request fully javascript rendered html source from a website and find all iframe tags

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to use selenium and BeautifulSoup to retrieve all iframe tags from a website. The problem is I am not getting all the iframes because there are inner html documents within the webpage that BS4 is not searching through and I don't believe the javascript is being executed within the HTML so there may be some HTML elements that aren't getting rendered. Is there a web scraping tool that would allow me to request a url, retrieve the fully js rendered HTML file then search through the DOM and get all tags matching iframe, even in the inner HTML code.

Basically I am able to see all the tags I want within the chrome inspector tool but they are not showing up in the list retrieved from find_all('iframe') function in BS4.

Here is the code I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/G/chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://reddit.com")

HTML = browser.page_source

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

page = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'html.parser')

for iframe in page.find_all('iframe'):
    print(iframe)

browser.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the `<iframe>` tags exclusively through **`Selenium`** with the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get("https://reddit.com")
frames_tag = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
frames_xpath = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")
frames_css = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("iframe")
print("Frames detected through iframe tag are %s" %frames_tag)
print("Frames detected through xpath are %s" %frames_xpath)
print("Frames detected through css are %s" %frames_css)
browser.quit()
```

The output on my console is :

```
Frames detected through iframe tag are [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="ead39d06-0e39-4b40-9425-a86a1fe88d4f")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="1ce10f29-a620-4ce6-90e1-9da563046c70")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="ba8493e4-8246-47a0-9ed4-3f51b8c0f133")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="19c0f134-c243-47bd-96d1-6b06ff66a011")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="95d78fa6-fb4f-4b7c-89c5-9b85965f0e4c")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="e6d2d931-1f35-432f-8825-052e244fe798")>]
Frames detected through xpath are [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="ead39d06-0e39-4b40-9425-a86a1fe88d4f")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="1ce10f29-a620-4ce6-90e1-9da563046c70")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="ba8493e4-8246-47a0-9ed4-3f51b8c0f133")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="19c0f134-c243-47bd-96d1-6b06ff66a011")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="95d78fa6-fb4f-4b7c-89c5-9b85965f0e4c")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="e6d2d931-1f35-432f-8825-052e244fe798")>]
Frames detected through css are [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="ead39d06-0e39-4b40-9425-a86a1fe88d4f")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="1ce10f29-a620-4ce6-90e1-9da563046c70")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="ba8493e4-8246-47a0-9ed4-3f51b8c0f133")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="19c0f134-c243-47bd-96d1-6b06ff66a011")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="95d78fa6-fb4f-4b7c-89c5-9b85965f0e4c")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98594106-54a6-4941-a6ab-cd9d92e9afa2", element="e6d2d931-1f35-432f-8825-052e244fe798")>]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I did have to add a sleep time before I called find_elements_by_tag_name and found more iframes that way. Anyway you know how to request the inner html created by the iframe?