# javascript error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function error clicking on a button using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using Selenium Webdriver with testng. On one of the WebElements I am trying to perform click on button action.
I am picking the locator "ID" and performing the below action.

```
WebDriver webDriver = this.getWebDriver();
webDriver.findElement(By.id("addTagBtn")).click();
```

and i am getting below error -

```
javascript error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function error
```

HTML code looks like below
[image]

Comment: You should show the actual code, not a picture of minified results in your console. The error means that `a.tagName` is not returning a string, which is what `toUpperCase()` needs in order to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when i used Javascript code i.e

````
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;  
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById('addTagBtn').click();");
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
javascript error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function error
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance attempted to invoke `click()` on the desired element even before the element was completely [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233385/request-fully-javascript-rendered-html-source-from-a-website-and-find-all-iframe/47237075#47237075) with in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

---

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element. So to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `id`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("addTagBtn"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td > button#addTagBtn"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/button[@id='addTagBtn' and text()='Add']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Used , new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("addTagBtn"))).click();
However this did not work.

Comment: @Ashu123 How about the xpath and css?

Comment: Tried - public boolean clickUponReactAddBtn(String descr) {
  boolean success = false;
  WebDriver webDriver = this.getWebDriver();
  
  new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td > button#addTagBtn"))).click();
 
  //new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/button[@id='addTagBtn' and text()='Add']"))).click();
 }
I am getting same error as "javascript error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function error"