# How to extract the value of href attribute containing javascript with Selenium ChromeDriver using GetAttribute method

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I noticed some results of call to GetAttribute provide not fully decoded strings.

```cs
var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"#lien_batiment_{id}"));
var href = element.GetAttribute("href");
```

Actual:

```cs
"javascript:f_affiche_contenu(9367718,'coopr_detail_batiment.php?id=9367718&filtre=32&contenuonly=1%27);"
```

Expected:

```cs
"javascript:f_affiche_contenu(9367718,'coopr_detail_batiment.php?id=9367718&filtre=32&contenuonly=1');"
```

If it was normal, first apostrophe should have been encoded too, and probably & too.

Expected value is provided as well by chrome developper panel. Edge provide the same, and it almost seems logic to have correct decoded JS to execute it with IJavaScriptExecutor.

I use a `href= href.Replace("%27","'")`, but it's not a serious option if I have js containing real decode %27 sequence.

Any Idea ?

Dependencies :

- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver **103.0.5060.13400**
- Selenium.WebDriver **4.3.0**
- Selenium.Support **4.3.0**
- .Net Framework **4.8**

here some more informations to reproduce :

```cs
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

using(var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions))
{
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://france2.simagri.com/");
   // have to login with account here
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Login")).SendKeys("login");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Password")).SendKeys("password");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("FAccesCompte")).Submit();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://france2.simagri.com/liste_batiment.php");
   // you need to have some batiments 
   var id = 9132371; // feed matching one

   var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"#lien_batiment_{id}"));
var href = element.GetAttribute("href");

}
```

as you can see, very simple...

Comment: If it's the expected value in chrome console, use execute_script to get it. You can always expect chrome to behave more properly than selenium

Comment: it doesnt change anything. really interesting... as JS script works on the website, then I suppose Chrome have a lazy mechanism. I noticed it monthes ago copying outer-html from developper tool with some not decode attribute, but I didnt expect API's will suffer the same problem

Comment: You'd have to post some code. It sounds like you're probably doing something silly.

Comment: I added at end of post. good chance with something silly :)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you need to wait a bit for the element to completely [render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) before you extract the *`href`* attribute inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the _`ElementIsVisible`_as follows:

```
var href = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector($"#lien_batiment_{id}"))).GetAttribute("href");
```

Comment: it doesnt change anything. If asynchronous work is the origin of problem, it's probably not at Selenium level. I'll try with more browsers to have an idea