# Can't send keys using multithreading with selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to use a multi-thread strategy with selenium. In shorts I'm trying to fill in input field with ids.

This is my script :

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import numpy as np
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

def driver_setup():
    path = "geckodriver.exe"
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=path)
    return driver


def fetcher(id, driver):
    print(id) #this works
    
    # this doesnt work
    driver.get(
        "https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="30_user_id"]').send_keys(id)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i, " sent")
    #return data

def crawler(ids):
    for id in ids:
        print(i)
        results = fetcher(id, driver_setup())

drivers = [driver_setup() for _ in range(4)]


ids = list(range(0,50)) # generates ids
print(ids)
chunks = np.array_split(np.array(ids),4) #splits the id list into 4 chunks

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    bucket = executor.map(crawler, chunks)
    #results = [item for block in bucket for item in block]

[driver.quit() for driver in drivers]
```

Everything seems to work except the send_keys method. Both print() works so it seems the ids are sent to both functions. Weirdly, I don't get an error message (i get the pycharm's Process finished with exit code 0 notice) so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any idea what is missing ?

I used this example : https://blog.devgenius.io/multi-threaded-web-scraping-with-selenium-dbcfb0635e83 if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using **threading**, watch out for **exceptions** as they get embedded into **futures**.
for example  change your code to have the below-tweaked code(don't change any other line yet)

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    bucket = executor.map(crawler, chunks)
    # bucket is list of futures, so let's try to print it
    for e_buck in bucket: # simpleapp add for demo
        print(e_buck) #
```

you will see that you will get exception errors like:

1. i is not defined, look at this statement `print(i, " sent")` and `print(i)` in crawler.
2. once you fix the above error, the next error will be in the id in send keys- `send_keys(id)`, `id is of type numpy.int64`. change it to str by typecast, str(), `send_keys(str(id))`

so your code, after fixes will be like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import numpy as np
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def driver_setup():
    path = "geckodriver.exe"
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=path)
    return driver


def fetcher(id, driver):
    print(id) #this works
    
    # this doesnt work - it will work now :)
    driver.get(
        "https://www.roboform.com/filling-test-all-fields")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="30_user_id"]').send_keys(str(id))
    time.sleep(2)
    print(id, " sent")
    #return data

def crawler(ids):
    for id in ids:
        print(id)
        results = fetcher(id, driver_setup())

#drivers = [driver_setup() for _ in range(4)]


ids = list(range(0,50)) # generates ids
print(ids)
chunks = np.array_split(np.array(ids),4) #splits the id list into 4 chunks

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    bucket = executor.map(crawler, chunks)
    # bucket is list of futures, so let's try to print it
    for e_buck in bucket: # simpleapp add for demo
        print(e_buck) # check what print, you get, first time you will get that
        # i is not defined, look at this statment print(i, " sent") and print(i) in crawler. 
        # once you fix the above error, next error will be in id in send keys- send_keys(id), id is of type ''numpy.int64''. change it to str by typecast, str(), send_keys(str(id))
    #results = [item for block in bucket for item in block]

#[driver.quit() for driver in drivers]
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you trying to invoke `send_keys()` too early even before the `<input>` field have [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) completely.

---

### Solution

Ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *NAME*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "30_user_id"))).send_keys(id)
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='30_user_id']"))).send_keys(id)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='30_user_id']"))).send_keys(id)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```