# Sending slash on send_keys on Selenium Chrome Driver on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I have been trying to send a URL link to a text area. I am using python3 and Chrome Version 109.0.5414.119. It worked fine on my local OSX machine but when I tried to automate it on a Linux Machine. It started behaving weirdly. So I have this feeling that It can be a Chrome Driver-related issue.

When I send a URL like this:

```
l.send_keys("https://google.com")
```

But becomes:

```
/google.comhttps:
```

Then I tried to debug this behavior by sending the following:

```
>>> l.send_keys("/") # /|
>>> l.send_keys("/") # |/
```

So the position of the cursor is going ahead of the line for the second `/`. I was not expecting this. I wonder if you can shed light on how to solve this?

Comment: Try click on `textarea` first and then use `send_keys()` to check whether that works?

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you are trying to invoke *`send_keys()`* too early within the `<input>` field even before the element have [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) properly.

---

### Solution

Ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_locator"))).send_keys("https://google.com")
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```